# ヘッダインクルード前の #define により，コンパイル内容を分岐・制御したい

Tags: c++, c

`print_test.hpp` のインクルード前に `#define` するかどうかで (例: `#define USEMYPRINT`)，
`print_test.hpp` および `print_test.cpp` 内を，`#ifdef` ~ `#else` ~ `#endif` により分岐させようとしています．

この際に `.cpp` ファイル内まで，`#define` で定義した内容が反映されませんでした．
このため，実体が生成されず，LNK 2019 エラーが発生してしまいます．
このような場合は，一般的にどのように解決されているでしょうか？

例えば，Eigen (線形代数演算ライブラリ) の場合，

```
#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG              // コード内のassertを無効化．
//#define EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE    // 並列を無効化．
//#define EIGEN_MPL2_ONLY           // LGPLライセンスのコードを使わない．
#include "Eigen/Dense"
```

のように，インクルード前に `#define` することで，`assert` の無効化等を行うことができ，
非常に便利だと感じました．(しかし，私には一見するだけでは，どのように実現しているかわから‌​ず……)

下記にかなり簡略化したサンプルを示します．(この場合，`.hpp` 内では，`#define USEMYPRINT` が認識されていますが，`.cpp` 内では，認識されず，実体が生成できないため，リンクエラーとなります)

よろしくお願いいたします．

環境 win8.1 Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 C++

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define USEMYPRINT // main.cpp 内でインクルード前に #define で定義されているかどうかにより，print_test.cpp および print_test.hpp で分岐を行いたい．
#include "print_test.hpp"

int main(){
    MyPrintf();
    return 0;
}
```

print_test.hpp

```
#pragma onece
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef USEMYPRINT
void MyPrintf();
#endif//USEMYPRINT
```

print_test.cpp

```
#include "print_test.hpp"

#ifdef USEMYPRINT
void MyPrintf(){
    printf("Hello my printf.\n");
}
#endif//USEMYPRINT
```

---

(みなさま，ご回答どうもありがとうございます．問題を解決することができました．
 また，自分で見直しても質問の意図が分かり難かったため，可能な限り修正いたしました)

---

具体性が乏しいとご指摘をいただきましたので，修正したサンプルコードを下記に示します．(余り具体性が増していませんが，実体は下記のコードと同じ構成です)
すみません．上記サンプルコードでは，実体を定義するかどうかとなっていますが，実際には，実体を定義するかしないかの制御 (sayuri 様のご回答により，出力されるバイナリに変化はないと分かったため，下記サンプルでは省略)，に加えて，文中で説明しているように，モードの切り替えも行いたい，と考えていました．

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Debug option
#define MyClass_Mode2
#include "MyClass.hpp"

int main(){
    class MyClass* p_mc = new MyClass();
    p_mc->MyFunction();
    delete p_mc;
    return 0;
}
```

MyClass.hpp

```
#pragma onece

#include <stdio.h>

class MyClass{
private:
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void MyFunction();
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"

void MyClass::MyFunction(){
#ifndef MyClass_Mode2
    printf("Mode1.\n");
#else
    printf("Mode2.\n");
#endif
}
```

Comment: print_test.cppが USEMYPRINTの定義しているファイルを参照していないので、常にundefindedになり、関数の実体がコンパイルされないためリンクエラーになっているのでは無いでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます．大変ややこしい話なのですが，普段は，print_test.hpp に #define USEMYPRINT を定義して， print_test.cpp から print_test.hpp をインクルードすることで解決してきました．
しかし，これでは，非常に不便なため，main.cpp ファイル内から制御したい，というのが，質問の趣旨となります．
乱暴な解決策としては，.hpp 内に .cpp の内容をすべて書き写せば済みますが，そういう訳にもいきませんので，何かよい解決策があるのだろうかと思って質問させていただきました．

例えば，Eigen (線形代数演算ライブラリ) を使用する場合，
#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG // コード内のassertを無効化．
#include "Eigen/Dense"
のように，インクルード前に #define することで，assert の無効化等を行うことができ，非常に便利だと感じました．(しかし，私には一見するだけでは，どのように実現しているのかわからず……)

Comment: Eigenはassertを呼び出す側もヘッダ内に書かれているので、「乱暴な解決策」に近いですね…。マクロを使えばMyPrintf()で呼び出される実装を切り替えることはできるでしょうが、コンパイルの有無を切り替えることはできないかと。 https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/e46c8246/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h#Macros.h-542

Comment: とても参考になります！`Eigen` の方法だと `assert()` 呼び出しを行うかどうかの分岐程度であれば，できそうですが，`.cpp` 内での `#define` による分岐まで処理するのは無理そうですね……．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一般的には、

```
#define USEMYPRINT // main.cpp 内でインクルード前に #define で定義されているかどうかにより，print_test.cpp および print_test.hpp で分岐を行いたい．
```

の様な定義は`プロジェクト名.hpp`等のファイルにまとめ、そのファイルを適宜インクルードするのが良いと思います。
今回の例ですと、

プログラム名.hpp

```
#define USEMYPRINT
```

main.cpp

```
#include "プログラム名.hpp"
#include "print_test.hpp"
```

print_test.hpp

```
#pragma onece
#include <stdio.h>
#include "プログラム名.hpp"

#ifdef USEMYPRINT
void MyPrintf();
#endif //USEMYPRINT
```

print_test.cpp

```
#include "プログラム名.hpp"
#include "print_test.hpp"

#ifdef USEMYPRINT
void MyPrintf(){
    printf("Hello my printf.\n");
}
#endif //USEMYPRINT
```

の様にして、.cppでの`#define`を避け、`#define`は必ずヘッダーファイルで行い、そのシンボルを参照するソースファイルは必ず`#define`をまとめたヘッダーファイルをインクルードするようにすると良いと思います。

Comment: 今回は分岐が複雑なので，この方法が一番確実そうです．この方向でコーディングを試みたいと思います！

Answer (score 0):

質問の趣旨がいまいちよくわからないため見当はずれな回答かもしれませんが、

コンパイラーオプション [/Gy; 関数レベルのリンクの有効化](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/xsa71f43.aspx) およびリンカーオプション [/OPT:NOREF; 参照されない関数とデータの削除](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bxwfs976.aspx) の機能があります。両機能を組み合わせることを前提にprint_test.cppファイル内で常に`MyPrintf()`を定義して構いませんし、print_test.hppファイル内で常に`MyPrintf()`を宣言して構いません。

main.cpp内で使用されなければ自動的に削除されます。

---

追記を受けて、やりようはいくらでもあると思います。
先述したように使用されなかった関数は消されますから両方定義してしまい、ヘッダーファイル内で分岐してしまうとか。クラス定義内に書かれた関数は自動的にインラインとなるため、最適化されればオーバーヘッドもないはずです。
これはあくまでテンプレート引数を嫌うコメントを受けての例です。

MyClass.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>


class MyClass {
private:
    void MyFunction_Mode1();
    void MyFunction_Mode2();
public:
    MyClass() = default;
    ~MyClass() = default;
    void MyFunction() {
#ifndef MyClass_Mode2
        MyFunction_Mode1();
#else
        MyFunction_Mode2();
#endif
    }
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"

#ifndef MyClass_Mode2
#define MyFunction MyFunction_Mode1
#else
#define MyFunction MyFunction_Mode2
#endif

void MyClass::MyFunction() {
#ifndef MyClass_Mode2
    printf("Mode1.\n");
#else
    printf("Mode2.\n");
#endif
}
```

MyClass_Mode2.cpp

```
#define MyClass_Mode2
#include "MyClass.cpp"
```

Comment: とんでもありません．勉強になります！今回の場合では .cpp 内の分岐が複雑になりますので， MyPrintf() の常時宣言 + コンパイラによる不要な実体の削除だけでは難しそうです．常時宣言で乗り切れそうな例に遭遇した際に実践してみたいと思います！

Comment: @ADMIS_Walker さん、C++言語の場合、例えば分岐する条件をテンプレートパラメーター引数で受け取るテンプレート関数を用意したりといろいろなアプローチがあるため、もう少し具体的な例を挙げてくれるとよりよいコードを提示できるかもしれません。

Comment: すみません．お返事遅くなりました．テンプレート関数では `.hpp` に記述する必要があることや，テンプレート引数など，なるべく引数として増やしたくない，`.hpp` に記述する場合 (恐らく) そもそもテンプレートを使用せずとも問題が解決するなどの理由から，今回はやめて置こうと思います．(最初にご説明すべきでしたが，今回は，ハッシュテーブルに使用するハッシュ関数の切り替えや，デバッグモードへの切り替えなどを想定していました) また，再度検討したところ，sayuri 様のご回答より，デバッグ用の関数をクラス内で定義する・しないを `#define` で制御する必要はないことがわかりました．(どの関数が，通常使用かデバッグ用か判断しにくくはなりますが，こちらは命名規則などで解決できそうです)